# Updating React Native Expo app, OTA vs build

Tags: expo

A few weeks ago I successfully uploaded my first app into the app stores. Now I have made updates. A lot of them, in fact. I changed many screens and how the app flow is. They are all javascript updates. I know that I could use OTA to publish these changes to live, but should I? They are big changes, but nothing sdk related or in app.json or anything that would require a standalone rebuild. But I'm wondering if I should still go through the app stores to push a new ipa/apk since it wasn't minor bug fixes or something small.

If I should push a new update through the app store, then could you please advise if this is the correct way to avoid publishing through expo before my new ipa/apk is approved? I just want to make sure I'm understanding the documentation I'm reading:

Run expo build on a specific RELEASE CHANNEL different from my previous one.
Submit those files to the app store as an update. Before they are approved, my live app will continue to pull from the previous published release channel.
Upon approval, the update will be live and expo will forever pull from the new published release channel. And I don't have to "do anything" with the old one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are correct. Ultimately it is up to you how you want to manage releases (your proposal seems reasonable). What I have been doing is keeping the release channel in sync with the build numbers. So I release version 2.6 on release channel prod-2-6. And my git branching strategy matches this so I can make bug fixes to specific versions.

One problem with publishing OTA updates and not releasing new versions to the app store is that, unless you have a very long [fallbackToCacheTimeout](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/) value, new users downloading the app for the first time will receive the version that is bundled with the app, and it won't be updated until they close and reopen the app or you handle the update yourself.

My strategy (there are others for sure) has been to make changes to the app, then publish on several past release-channels *and* post a new version to the app store. It isn't time consuming and this way you can update screenshots or anything else as needed. And you have the most number of people on the latest code version.

This also answers your question of how to not update existing users: if the release-channel is the same as the build number then you can keep versions distinct.